# Where did I go wrong? Input and output

Tags: python

Going back to basics and I'm struggling to do a simple task of asking for a name and age and I can't output when the user will turn 100) Help

```
name = input("Please enter your name")
print("Hello "+ name)
age = (int(input("How old are you?")))
print("You will be 100 years old in year {}").format(2019) + (age-100)
```

Comment: I think you want `.format(2019 + 100 - age)`.

Comment: `print("You will be 100 years old in year {}").format(2019) + (age-100)` This requests to put the `2019` into the string, print it, then add *the result of the print()` call* to `(age - 100)`. Think more clearly about the order of operation.

Comment: You are missing a condition statement. Having determine the current age of a person x. you will need to add an if statement....  to check if the current person is younger than or older than this age bracket. Example; if( person x > 100) then print the age.

Answer (score 1):

As of python 3.6, the most pythonic way to include a variable in a string is using f-strings.

Put the letter f before the string you want to format, and then the name of the variable you want to have in the string inside braces (curly brackets {}).

```
name = input("Please enter your name")
print(f"Hello {name}")
age = (int(input("How old are you?")))
year = 2019 + 100 - age
print(f"You will be 100 years old in year {year}")
```

You could also perform the calculation inside the f-string if you wish.

```
print(f"You will be 100 years old in year {2019 + 100 - age}")
```

Comment: Oh wow, that makes it so much easier than the .format method. Thank for you very much